# Update empty form field before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user clicks the button to submit an HTML form, I would like to check if one of the inputs (used to capture an email address) has any content. (i.e. Has the user entered their email address?)

If so, submit the form.

If not, fill the input with something (e.g. hello@hello.com) that is hidden for the user and then submit the form.

I have tried a number of things, but whatever I do seems to interrupt the submit part of the form.

Comment: *If not, fill the input with something (e.g. hello@hello.com) that is hidden for the user and then submit the form.*.. why do this?  That seems inefficient, and plus email addresses should be unique so you shouldn't fill that field with the same email every time the user doesn't fill it out..  Email addresses should be **required**

Comment: Could you show us what you did by providing a [mcve] to your question ?

Comment: Intercept the onsubmit event of this form, and return false when any input is invalid.

Comment: @T_Roy The form is getting sent to Pardot, which requires an email address. We implemented this and saw our conversion rate drop considerably (most users are over 70) so are looking at a way to continue using Pardot (for those with email address) without alienating those who might not have an email or who don't wish to leave one.

Comment: @Ben does Pardot require the email address to be written in an exact way?  Or can you get away with something like 'No email' in the email field?

Comment: @T_Roy Yes, it requires it to be formatted as an email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use the `defaulValue` property of the input element which, as the name suggests, will asignn a default value to the input element if nothing is entered

```js
document.querySelector('form')
        .addEventListener('submit', function(e){
                                      var rem = Array.from({length:15})
                                                     .reduce(r => Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + r,"@hello.com");
                                      e.target.em.defaultValue = rem;
                                      console.log(e.target.em.value);
                                    });
```

```html
<form>
  <label>email:</label>
  <input name="em" type="email" placeholder="abc@xyz.com" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and once the form is submitted it's refreshed anyways.

I have modified the code to include a random email generator whose result is assigned to the `rem` variable. It's quite simple;

```
var rem = Array.from({length:15}) // generate an empty array of length 15
               .reduce(r => Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + r,"@hello.com");
```

It generates an array of length 15 (`Array.from({length:15})`) and then reduces with an initial value of `"@hello.com"` which is the `r` in the callback. In each turn it prepends an random integer among 0-9 to the initial value (`"@hello.com"`) and returns an email address string like `642273534410880@hello.com`.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. I tried it first as it seemed the most straightforward of those offered. It worked well. I wonder if you could tell me how I could alter the code so the email is a random string of 15 numbers followed by @hello.com. e.g 786376478735676@hello.com

Comment: @Ben Thank you i have modified the code to include a random email address string generator. Explanation annexed at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Many thanks. Worked perfectly and very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just listen to the `submit` event of the form, check the field is not empty. If it is, you can store data in `input[type="hidden"]` that will send to the server to.

I'm using `e.preventDefault` so the form will not submitted.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var email = e.target.email.value;
  if (!email) {
    document.querySelector('#hidden').value = 'hello@hello.com';
  }
  
  console.log(document.querySelector('#hidden').value);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden" />
  <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="email" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Actually the question says he wants to submit the form, even if there is nothing in email field

Comment: @ankit_sharma I know, I mention this in my answer. I just wanted that he could see the affect. If the form will submitted he couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

- Handle the `onClick` of the button (which makes the server call) in client side
- Perform your validations inside that handler function
- Return `true` (continue with the server call) if you are happy with the validations
- Return `false` (cancel the server call) if you are not happy with the validation.

Now when the validation fails, if you want to continue the server call with some *default* values, you should write them in the click handler before returning `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a submit button in your HTML, may be something like this :

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="checkInputFields()" />
```

Pay attention to checkInputFields function , within this you can add logic something along these lines :

```
function checkInputFields() {
   // your usual submit logic
    var emailAddress;
    emailAddress = document.getElementById("emailAddressID").value;
    if (emailAddress == "") {
        //email address is not present
        // create a unique dummy email address
        var emailAddress = "DummyEmail" + Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
     .toString(16)
      .substring(1)+ "@hello.com"

    };
}
```

Please note that emails IDs are not actually unique but this should give you a starting point.